# Using swiper for dynamic data?

Tags: ionic-framework, swiper.js

What is the best way to show a indeterministic number of images using swiper?  The list could be as few as 1-5 images.  It could be tens, hundreds, or even thousand.

If the number is large, it doesn't make sense to have all `swiper-slide` in the DOM.